# fragment a string into various components using python

Tags: python, dataframe, text, split, analytics

`RELATED APPLICATIONS\nThis application cla...... 2006.\nTECHNICAL FIELD\nThis application relates to t.....e number.\nBACKGROUND\nUser-initiated money and funds tra.....sfer and/or payment.\nSUMMARY\nA system and method for p.......als.\nDETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE PREFERRED EMBODIMENTS\nThe following detailed d.....`

i want the output be like
`RELATED APPLICATIONS="This application cla...... 2006."`
`TECHNICAL FIELD="This application relates to t.....e number."`
`BACKGROUND="User-initiated money and funds tra.....sfer and/or payment."`
`SUMMARY="A system and method for p.......als."`
`DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE PREFERRED EMBODIMENTS="The following detailed d....."`
`note:- "\n" can't be used to fragment as it has been used inside the BACKGROUND lot of times.`

I have tried regex, but nothing worked.

Comment: 1- please format the question properly, it's currently difficult to read. 2- how is this related to dataframe? Please give a clear reproducible object as input 3- provide the code of what you tried and which failed.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is a bit difficult to read perhaps this could help:

```
str="RELATED_APPLICATION\nThis application cla...... 2006.\nTECHNICAL FIELD\nThis application relates to t.....e number.\nBACKGROUND\nUser-initiated money and funds tra.....sfer and/or payment.\nSUMMARY\nA system and method for p.......als.\nDETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE PREFERRED EMBODIMENTS\nThe following detailed d"
#Replace each new line with = sign
mystr=str.replace("\n","=")
#Split the string on .= substring
mystr=mystr.split(".=")
for strx in mystr:
    print(strx)
```